# Why is this test expression an error?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, polymorphism

i want to understand why the C# language decided to make this test expression as an error.

```
interface IA { }
interface IB { }
class Foo : IA, IB { }
class Program
{
    static void testFunction<T>(T obj) where T : IA, IB
    {
        IA obj2 = obj;

        if (obj == obj2) //ERROR
        {

        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo myFoo = new Foo();
        testFunction(myFoo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In the testFunction, i can make an object called obj2 and set it to obj implicitly without casting it. But why cant i then check the two objects to see if they are the same, without casting it? They obviously implement the same interface, so why is it an error?

Comment: Common interface does not an equivalence make...

Comment: If it compiled, what should it do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check to see if they're the same object by using [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) or [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx).

However, since your constraints (`IA` and `IB` interfaces) don't enforce that the type is necessarily a reference type, there's no guarantee that the equality operator can be used.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you construct T with a value type X that implements IA.

What does

```
static void testFunction<T>(T obj) where T : IA
{
    IA obj2 = obj;
    if (obj == obj2) //ERROR
```

do when called as `testFunction<X>(new X(whatever))` ?

T is X, X implements IA, so the implicit conversion boxes obj to obj2.

The equality operator is now comparing a value type X with a boxed copy of compile-time type IA. That the runtime type is a boxed X the compiler does not care about; that information is ignored.

What comparison semantics should it use?

It cannot use *reference* comparison semantics because that would mean that obj would also have to be boxed. It won't box to the same reference, so this would *always* be false, which seems bad.

It cannot use *value* comparison semantics because the compiler has no basis upon which kind of value semantics it should use!  At compile time it does not know whether the type chosen for T in the future will provide an overloaded == operator or not, and even if it does, that operator is unlikely to take an IA as one of its operands.

There are no equality semantics that the compiler can reasonably choose, and therefore this is illegal.

Now, if you constrain T to be a reference type then the first objection goes away, and the compiler can reasonably choose reference equality.  If that's your intention then constrain T to be a reference type.

Answer (score 6):

To expand a bit on Reed's answer (which is certainly correct):

Note that the following code results in the same error at compile time:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid(); // a value type
object o = g;

if (o == g) // ERROR
{
}
```

The C# language specification says (§7.10.6):

> The predefined reference type equality operators are:
>
> - `bool operator ==(object x, object y);`
> - `bool operator !=(object x, object y);`
>
> [...]
>
> The predefined reference type equality operators require one of the following:
>
> - Both operands are a value of a type known to be a *reference-type* or the literal `null`.
>     Furthermore, an explicit reference conversion (§6.2.4) exists from the type of either operand to the type of the other operand.
> - One operand is a value of type `T` where `T` is a *type-parameter* and the other operand is the literal `null`. Furthermore T does not have the value type constraint.
>
> [...]
>
> Unless one of these conditions are true, a binding-time error occurs. Notable implications of these rules are:
>
> [...]
>
> - The predefined reference type equality operators do not permit value type operands to be compared. Therefore, unless a struct type declares its own equality operators, it is not possible to compare values of that struct type.
> - The predefined reference type equality operators never cause boxing operations to occur for their operands. It would be meaningless to perform such boxing operations, since references to the newly allocated boxed instances would necessarily differ from all other references.

Now, in your code example you do not constrain `T` to be a reference type and hence you get the compile-time error. Your sample can be fixed however by declaring that `T` must be a reference type:

```
static void testFunction<T>(T obj) where T : class, IA, IB
{
    IA obj2 = obj;

    if (obj == obj2) // compiles fine
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    if (obj.Equals(obj2))
```

IA doesn't implement any == operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh thanks Reed Copsey for that note.

I just also found out that you can put "class" in the where clause like this.

```
    static void testFunction<T>(T obj) where T : class, IA, IB
    {
        IA obj2 = obj;

        if (obj == obj2)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now its a reference type and it works! :-)

Comment: But if it's important that you do a reference comparison it's probably best to call that out and use `ReferenceEquals` anyway, to make the code clearer.